# i18next, react and HTML provided as a variable

Tags: html, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a project where users can provide a text for searching. This text CAN be HTML, and because of it, we won't escape it, as in the source, it is not escaped.

We provide a whole bunch of functionality, including deleting not needed searches.

We support many languages (including Japanese, among others), and therefore we cannot decide upfront in which place in translation the search we want to delete will be placed. So we use `Trans` component. And here the problem starts.

React itself handles HTML strings quite well. It just displays source code `<a href="example.com">link</a>`. But `Trans` interprets HTML (and displays [link](https://example.com)) or escapes HTML and displays `&lt;a href="example.com"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;`.

I tried changing options (like `escapeValue`) or manually working with the string, which is passed as a value to translation. Nothing works as expected.

Is there any way to force `Trans` to behave as a react component and display HTML source code?

Comment: If you want to display HTML source code as formatted text, take a look at Reacts `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: and how to use it with `Trans` component of i18next ?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-snowflake-17k3xq I want only a variable named `htmlValue` to be displayed as it was provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

in `i18n.init` set

```
interpolation: {
  escapeValue: true
}
```

Then in your `Trans` component, use prop:

```
shouldUnescape={true}
```

Working codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-microservice-2l5jd6)